# How to collect all checkbox elements inside of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a big div element and there are multiple div and input (checkbox type) tags inside of it. I want to check that if all checkboxes are checked or no. I try the following JQuery snippet to refer to all checkboxes inside the div:

```
$('div#mainDiv-checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    //my logic
});
```

but it doesn't get all checkboxes. What is the reliable jquery selector for this kind of situation? there is no order for the position of input elements in my page. I mean there can be everywhere inside of the main div.

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `if($('div#mainDiv-checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked').length==$('div#mainDiv-checkboxes input[type=checkbox]'))` means all are checked

Comment: What exactly doesn't work the way you expect? Looks like this part of your code is fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this work without `each()`. Get count of all `checkbox` and `checked` checkbox. If both of value is equal, that means all checkbox is checked.

```js
$("button").click(function(){    
    var all = $("div :checkbox").length;
    var checked = $("div :checkbox:checked").length;
    
    if (all == checked)
        console.log("All checkbox is checked!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Get the number of all checkboxes. Get the number of *checked* checkboxes.

If the numbers are the same, all are checked.

```
var container = document.querySelector('#mainDiv-checkboxes');
var checkboxesAll = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var checkBoxesSelected = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/90uu35bs/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelectors` as well to fetch element and try [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to validate.

#### Sample

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/hkL439tm/).

```js
function validate() {
  var chks = document.querySelectorAll("#content input[type='checkbox']");
  var result = Array.prototype.every.call(chks, function(c) {
    return c.checked;
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <input type="checkbox" />a
  <input type="checkbox" />b
  <input type="checkbox" />c
  <input type="checkbox" />d
</div>

<button onclick="validate()">Test</button>
```

**Note:** array.every is not supported by every browser. Check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Browser_compatibility) before using it.